# Word 2016 Add-in: This add-in is no longer available

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office365-apps

I developed a Word 2016 Add-in using Visual Studio 2015 + Office 2016.
I've recently moved to Office 365, since the MSI version of Office 2016 doesn't support the new features of Word API library.

As I opened the project and tried to run in debug, I noticed that it wasn't working.
Word opens showing this error message inside the add-in taskpane:

> Error : "This add-in is no longer available: addin inserted during
>   development are only available during debugging from visual studio.
>   Please open your project in visual studio and re-run your application
>   or deploy your add-in into a valid catalog and reinsert."

Also the published version of the add-in - installed from a shared network folder - isn't available anymore: the manifest isn't listed in Insert > Store > Shared Folder dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigations it turns out that if I replace in manifest every occurrence of my custom namespace with the default "Contoso", everything works fine:

```
<Title resid="MyCompany.GetStarted.Title"/>
<Title resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Title"/>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

My add-in had a custom ribbon/buttons which is not supported in the desktop for my version of Word: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/add-in-commands-requirement-sets.

Removing the ribbon worked for me.